# Hudson Plugin for svn merge

Tags: svn, hudson-plugins

Does anyone know if there is a hudson plugin for post build merging into a specified branch.
I saw the jenkins svn-merge plugin and tried it but the new field that appears at the bottom of the screen references a field that is supposed to exist earlier in the build config but does not.
I'm not looking for an ant script or to include anything else to the maven build. just a plugin that would allow a merge specific to that configuration.

Thanks, Al

Comment: unless the merge was trivial, it would require user interaction.  Not sure if a plugin could exist that could handle that.  But I may be wrong, however I have not seen anything like that.

Comment: I would assuma a trivial merge. I have installed the jenkins svn-merge plugin but it does not seem to work with hudson, or the more likely case I am doing something wrong.  

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Merge+Plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question above was: "use Jenkins and upgrade subversion"
The biggest problem was that the version of Subversion I was using was way to old.
after upgrading subversion and installing Jenkins the world was alight with rainbows and unicorns and my woe's had been defeated.